# Display array in Angular2 template

Tags: angular, binding

My angular2 component has an `@Input(): data` of type `[number,number]`. The size of the array is should be determined from the input. How can I now bind the content of this array to a table in html, i.e., the table should be something like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td> data[0,0] </td>
        <td> data[0,1] </td>
        ...
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> data[1,0] </td>
        <td> data[1,1] </td>
        ...
    </tr>
    ...
</table>
```

Comment: If length of the array is determined from the input, you can define type data like `@Input() data: number[];`. Can you show example input for easy understand problem?

Comment: @Jarek: It is a two-dimensional array of size (n,m). Each entry is an integer. By "the length is determined from input" I mean that the component does not know the size intrinsically, only when it get's the data.

Comment: So you have only problem with display data, yes?

Comment: @Jarek I want to bind it in the html template using something like `*ngFor`, yes.

Comment: If that's the two-dimensional array using the wrong type period That's a tuple type

Comment: I added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with two *ngFor-Directives:

```
<table>
    <tr *ngFor="let row of data">
        <td *ngFor="let value of row">{{value}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Working [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/qHJLWsO5NvOz0uNOtcQu?p=preview)

Comment: I should have looked at arrays in js closer. I didn't know they are interpreted as an array of arrays, i.e, an array of rows containin the array of cells. Then it is obvious, thank you. I was more thinking like one double-indexed data structure.

Answer (score 1):

Short example:

Our array:

```
array = [[1,2],[3,4],[7,7]];
```

Our template:

```
<table>
  <tr *ngFor="let rows of array">
    <td *ngFor="let col of rows">{{ col }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, see my comment to @Markai 's answer.