# how to display the array inside json in ionic card

Tags: json, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

consider the below json data

```
    [{
    "id":"1",
    "name": "abc",
    "url": "www.abc.com",
    "img":"abc.jpeg",
    "yield": "12",
    "ingredients":[
      "1 cup Rice flour<br/>",
      "2 cups Water<br/>",
      "1 teaspoon Cooking oil<br/>",
      "1/2 teaspoon Salt<br/>",
      "1 cup Fresh coconut , grated<br/>",
      "1/2 cup Jaggery<br/>",
      "1 teaspoon Cardamom Powder<br/>"
    ]
}]
```

Now when i tried to print ingredients in ionic-card-content Its showing as a paragraph

```
 <ion-card-content class="item item-text-wrap">{{ recepie.ingredients }
```

o/p

> 1 cup Rice flour,2 cups Water,1 teaspoon Cooking oil,1/2 teaspoon
>   Salt,1 cup Fresh coconut , grated,1/2 cup Jaggery,1 teaspoon Cardamom
>   Powder

But i need those ingredients to be printed in each line in ionic card. with divider

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display array in Angular2 template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42626727/display-array-in-angular2-template)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the *ngFor directive, see the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ngfor).

```
<ion-card-content class="item item-text-wrap">
  <p *ngFor="let ingredient of recepie.ingredients">{{ ingredient }}</p>
</ion-card-content>
```

Comment: amazing thanks for helping can i add a divider like thing here ?

Comment: If you want to add more elements, put the `*ngFor` in a container (e.g. a `div`) and all its children will be repeated for each element of the array. `<div *ngFor="let item of items">...</div>`

Answer (score 0):

With respect to your json file because your json file data is in array;

```
myData= [
  {
    "id":"1",
    "name": "abc",
    "url": "www.abc.com",
    "img":"abc.jpeg",
    "yield": "12",
    "ingredients":[
      "1 cup Rice flour<br/>",
      "2 cups Water<br/>",
      "1 teaspoon Cooking oil<br/>",
      "1/2 teaspoon Salt<br/>",
      "1 cup Fresh coconut , grated<br/>",
      "1/2 cup Jaggery<br/>",
      "1 teaspoon Cardamom Powder<br/>"
    ]
 },
 {
    "id":"2",
    "name": "xyz",
    "url": "www.xyz.com",
    "img":"xyz.jpeg",
    "yield": "12",
    "ingredients":[
      "3 cup Rice flour<br/>",
      "1 cups Water<br/>",
      "1 teaspoon Cooking oil<br/>",
      "3/2 teaspoon Salt<br/>",
      "2 cup Fresh coconut , grated<br/>",
      "1/2 cup Jaggery<br/>",
      "1 teaspoon Cardamom Powder<br/>"
    ]
 }
]
```

the html code must be like that

```
<ion-card-content class="item item-text-wrap" *ngFor= let item of myData>
  <p *ngFor="let ingredient of item.ingredients" class= >{{ ingredient }}</p>
</ion-card-content>
```